# Commutativity in permutation group

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutations

Suppose $G=S_n$ is the permutation group in $n$ letters and $7\leq n\leq 10$. Also consider the subgroups $H_1,H_2$ such that $H_1$ is isomorphic with $S_k$ and $H_2$ is isomorphic with $S_{n-k}$ and every element of $H_1$ commutes with every element of $H_2$. Is it true that $H_1,H_2$ are the stabilizers of $n-k$ and $k$ letters respectively?

Comment: For $k=1,2,3,\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, you should consider all possible actions of $S_{n-k}$ (or $S_k$, if easier) on $n$ elements, compute their centralizers and check what's going on. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Y Cor, I need to have a proof with less computation.

Comment: $S_5$ has a transitive action in $S_6$, and the centralizer is $S_1$ (i.e. the trivial group). So there's a counter-example. There might be others for small $n$. But I'd expect the statement is true for $n$ large enough -- use the fact that the centralizer of a transitive group is semi-regular.

Comment: By the way, I don't understand why there is a vote to close. The question seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: @NickGill I voted not to close, but to move it to MathStackexchange. I agree that the question is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Nick, Consider $k\geq 2$. For $k=1$, the question is not interesting.

Comment: @YCor, Fair enough. I think the question is OK here. But MSE would be fine too.

Comment: A similar idea to Nick's gives a counterexample with $k=2$ or $k=3$. $S_6$ has an outer automorphism (this sends the stabilizer of a point to the transitive $S_5$ Nick mentioned). So consider stabilizers of $6-k$ and $k$ letters in $S_6$ (for $k=2$ and $k=3$) and then take their images under the outer automorphism.

Comment: I think YCor's first comment reduces the question to a straightforward exercise for $n \ge 7$, so I agree with the suggestion of moving it to MSE.

Comment: @YCor, How can I find all action of $S_k$ on $n$ elements?

Comment: $n$ already exists, let's say on $d$ elements. You first reduce to the transitive case. You have the action on the singleton, the action on 2 elements through the signature. Assuming $k\ge 2$, other transitive actions are faithful and thus $d\ge k$. For $d=k$ up to an automorphism you have the regular action by permutations. For $d>k$ you need to determine the subgroups of index $d$ in $S_k$, and you can hope that there are none, for obvious or non-obvious reasons (e.g., obviously $S_6$ has no subgroup of index 7, and it's a little exercise that it has no subgroup of index 8 or 9).

Answer (score 1):

Pick a prime $p$ in the range $\frac{n}{2}<p\leq n-k$. Then $S_{n-k}$ contains $(p-1)!\binom{n-k}{p}$ elements of order $p$, and elements of order $p$ in $S_n$ are $p$-cycles. There are at most $(p-1)!$ cycles of length $p$ in $H_2$, which move the same $p$ points, hence $H_1$ fixes the union of $\geq\binom{n-k}{p}$ sets of size $p$ pointwise, and this union has $\geq n-k$ elements. Hence $H_1$ is the stabilizer of a set of $\geq n-k$ points, and $>$ is clearly impossible.

If there is no prime in this range, things get a bit more complicated. Suppose $p<q$ are primes with $p+q\leq n-k$. Then an element of order $pq$ in $H_2$ consists of $\alpha$ cycles of length $p$ and $\beta$ cycles of length $q$. If $\alpha=\beta=1$, you can argue as above. Otherwise the centralizer of this element in $H_1$ has order $\leq \alpha! \beta! p^{\alpha-1} q^{\beta-1}(n-\alpha p - \beta q)!$, which will usually be smaller than $k!$, and you obtain a contradiction.